# error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core` note: the `thumbv7m-none-eabi` target may not be installed

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to blink the led on a bluepill (arm STM32) and followed the instructions from this [tutorial](https://jonathanklimt.de/electronics/programming/embedded-rust/rust-on-stm32-2/), but i run into this error when i try to compile the code. i use ubuntu.

i just installed rust / cargo as figured in the tutorial.
i have [stlink](https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink) installed, i have no experience with rust, cargo or bluepil.

```
$ cargo build --release:

        error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
      |
      = note: the `thumbv7m-none-eabi` target may not be installed
```

does it depend on the ./cargo/config file?

```
$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/marco/snap/rustup/common/rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

thumbv7m-none-eabi
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.46.0 (04488afe3 2020-08-24)
```

```
$ rustup target add thumbv7em-none-eabi
info: downloading component 'rust-std' for 'thumbv7em-none-eabi'
info: installing component 'rust-std' for 'thumbv7em-none-eabi'
info: Defaulting to 500.0 MiB unpack ram
```

```
$ cargo build --release
   Compiling semver-parser v0.7.0
   Compiling typenum v1.12.0
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.19
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.1
   Compiling syn v1.0.39
   Compiling stable_deref_trait v1.2.0
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `thumbv7m-none-eabi` target may not be installed
```

Does it depend on the name in the "Cargo.toml" file? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The code you've provided compiles fine for me.

Comment: this is the code (https://jonathanklimt.de/electronics/programming/embedded-rust/rust-on-stm32-2/) and i followed the instruction from here, but it doesn't compile.i get the errors as mentioned in my post.

Comment: [To make Stack Overflow a useful resource for future visitors beyond the context of your repository](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/155423), please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] in the question itself, in addition to the link to your repository.

Comment: i updated the question, better?

Comment: @NaturalDemon did you install your crate in the `cargo.toml` file...?

Comment: it came with the project, i just copied it and placed it in the folder as stated in the tutorial. the question is, why does it say: note: the `thumbv7m-none-eabi` target may not be installed, but if i do "$ rustup show" the toolchain is installed.

Answer (score 5):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```